# How to design a superhero rpg around a certain power level?

Tags: game-design, supers

A common thing in superhero rpgs is that they're designed for all characters to be within a specific power range, mainly for balance purposes and not having to deal with absurd situations like Aunt May being able to beat the Juggernaut in an arm-wrestling contest. Common categories are low-level, where characters often have no powers at all or aren't all that impressive (think Gotham city), mid-level which would be the marvel universe basically, and then high-level where everyone's on level with superman.

However, thinking about it, I do not know what makes a game better for each level. I've only seen two super hero games, and they have nothing in common. One is the DC Universe game that uses the new Mutants and Masterminds system. The other is a mid-level game that I'd rather not name (lets just say its developer won't ever see the sun again for things he's done, besides the game isn't available anymore and hasn't been for years).

I did notice that the DC game wasn't very good at representing low-level characters. Its build for Batman for instance had enough strength to lift a thug over his head and throw them over 100 feet away according to the game's math. Clearly it was better at representing things like Superman. As for that mid-tier system, strangely it worked best for mid-level characters. It could handle low-level characters decently enough, along with high-level characters, though it didn't do so optimally. Notably, high-tier characters weren't more powerful than their mid-tier counterparts; they just had more powers to use up more creation points.

How exactly do you create a game that's geared towards these three different levels of play? I would like my game to be able to switch between them honestly. Similar to how the various tri-stat games had you rolling different dice depending on the power level of the game in question, but as said I would have no idea how to gear a game towards a specific level of play. Even if I didn't do this, I wouldn't know how to gear my game towards specific types of characters. How is this normally accomplished? As for the DC game, its main problem really was the logarithmic scaling (every +1 to an attribute doubled its effectiveness), so there was far more high levels than low ones.

Answer (score 3):

### Characteristic Caps

I'm not familiar with the DC implementation of Mutants & Masterminds, but the base version handles power level by putting a hard cap on various characteristics. Those caps are derived from a characteristic loosely analogous to character level, which is set by the GM and not subject to advancement.

So, in your specific example, it's unlikely that Aunt May beats the Juggernaut because she has a lower power level and simply *can't* ever get as big a bonus. If she has a giant pile of experience, she can broaden out a lot, but she can never pump up her strength beyond normal-human (or whatever power level).

Mutants & Masterminds leans into this pretty hard, but other systems do similar things. For example, nearly every game originally by White Wolf has a core "awesomeness" stat that helps put a floor and a ceiling on your performance (essence, arete, blood potency, etc.)

Obviously there are other ways you could go after this, but this and [Hobgoblin's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/209919/25662) are what I expect to see for superhero games.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a point-buy based system, with different point budgets for different types of superhero and levels of play. A well known one is [Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champions_(role-playing_game)) which was also generalized later into the generic [HERO System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_System). It is designed exactly for what you have in mind.

[Champions Complete](https://www.herogames.com/store/product/3-champions-complete-pdf/) p. 9 for example provides the following explanation and table for different types of characters worth different points:

> *Champions* campaigns fall into one of two types: Superheroic or Heroic. These campaign types affect how many CP you build characters on, and what you can do with those CP.
> *Most Champions campaigns are Superheroic*. In a Superheroic campaign, characters tend to start with more CP, and can usually buy Powers or any other character abilities with few restrictions.
> In a *Heroic* campaign, characters tend to start with fewer CP, and more restrictions on spending them. For example, characters in a Heroic campaign might be able to buy Characteristics, Skills, Perks, Talents, and only Powers that extend abilities all characters have by default (like Running or Swimming); if they can buy other Powers at all, they're likely to be heavily restricted by power level or usage requirement

| Character type (example) | Character Points |
| --- | --- |
| **Normal** |  |
| Standard normal | 25 |
| Skilled normal | 50 |
| Competent normal | 100 |
| **Heroic** |  |
| Standard (elite agents) | 175 |
| Powerful (urban vigilantes) | 225 |
| Very Powerful (mystery men) | 275 |
| **Superheroic** |  |
| Low-Powered (youthful superheroes) | 300 |
| Standard (important superheroes) | 400 |
| High-Powered (nation's greatest superheroes) | 500 |
| Very High-Powered (world's greatest superheroes) | 650 |
| Cosmically Powerful (galactic superheroes) | 750+ |